# Is there a way to retrieve json data based on logic or need of my app?

Tags: flutter

In my app,I want to retrieve json data from **api**,but my json file is too complex and large.so I want specific data according to my app needs every time when I call api and save that data directly into sqlite database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you need to only parse the data which you require, If you want to make this easy for you, use the extension in vs code, called DART DATA CLASS GENERATOR. It makes everything easy.
But, I would strongly suggest if you are new to the programming then learn DATA MODELLING.